# Проблема с архитектурой в веб

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, архитектура, php

Люди, подскажите пожалуйста, вопрос в следующем. Есть три файла - php который прогружается с самого начала, js в котором куча аякса и понятно дело php-обработчик. С самого начала принтится минимум из первого файла, в js'е стоят необходимые обработчики для того, чтобы подгрузить из базы все что нужно, плюс обработчики событий. Каждый обработчик на подгружаемый контент(принты дивов и т.д. из обработчиков) вешается в success у аякса. Соответственно, если в начале файла я пишу что-то типа data: act: "read", и продолжаю это по цепочке вниз вплоть до опустошения основного дива и подгрузки в него контента с обновленными данными, все изначальные обработчики (как то "update", "create", "delete"), изживают себя. Вариант есть использовать метод $.live(), но он устарел. Что делать? Как это должно концептуально выглядеть?

> Файл js - http://pastebin.com/jvcm0tnC

Answer (score 1):

Можно делегировать события через on(): $('body').on('click', '.class-of-element', funcForEvent);

Т.е. второй аргумент on() будет селектором, на который вешается обработчик внутри $('body')